# Some Images not rendered on react native Android (release mode only)

Tags: android, react-native

For some reason I don't understand, some images of my app do not render in Android release mode. The only log in logcat I've found about that are:

```
01-16 16:15:18.298 13322-13816/? W/unknown:ProgressiveDecoder: unknown image format, {uri: res:/2131231024, firstEncodedBytes: 3C3F786D6C2076657273, length: 6953}
01-16 16:15:18.306 13322-13823/? W/unknown:ProgressiveDecoder: unknown image format, {uri: res:/2131231033, firstEncodedBytes: 3C3F786D6C2076657273, length: 2567}
01-16 16:15:18.313 13322-13823/? W/unknown:ProgressiveDecoder: unknown image format, {uri: res:/2131231032, firstEncodedBytes: 3C3F786D6C2076657273, length: 2808}
01-16 16:15:18.317 13322-13616/? W/unknown:ProgressiveDecoder: unknown image format, {uri: res:/2131231033, firstEncodedBytes: 3C3F786D6C2076657273, length: 2567}
```

What would be the reason?

They are normal and simple png files and other very similar png files render correctly at the same place...

I've searched for similar issues but the only one I've found are fesco issues which are unfortunately different...

Help would be greatly appreciated.

More context info here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23022

Comment: Having the same issue. Any resolution on your end? Corrupt file maybe?

Comment: Well, I do not remember how did I solve that. I think it might be because the images were too big and resizing them down did solve the problem. Can you please check it at your end?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We're currently investigating the issue. We don't think it is a sizing issue as we're already optimizing them for mobile devices. Our hunch is that it is an image caching issue with the `react-native-fast-image` library. But we'll see...